# React: Problem with adding active state classes to one component at a time, and removing the active classes from the other components (ON CLICK)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, tailwind-css

I would like to add "flex-[5] class" to the active component, and "opacity-100" to the h3 inside the component.

My problem is that currently it doesn't remove the class from the previous components after I click on an other component.

I want only ONE component at a time to have the active classes.

```
import "./Project.css";
import Panel from "./Panel.jsx";

export default function Project() {
  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="container flex gap-5 w-[100vw] sm:w-[90vw]
        [&>#active]:flex-[5]
        [&>#active>h3]:opacity-100
        [&>#active>h3]:transition-opacity
        [&>#active>h3]:duration-300
        [&>#active>h3]:ease-in
        [&>#active>h3]:delay-[400ms]
      "
      >
        <Panel title={"Nature 1"} />
        <Panel title={"Nature 2"} />
        <Panel title={"Nature 3"} />
        <Panel title={"Nature 4"} />
        <Panel title={"Nature 5"} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Panel(props) {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(null);

  function activeState() {
    setActive("active");
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div
        onClick={activeState}
        id={active}
        className="bg-[url('./assets/img/nature-1.jpg')] nth-of-type(4)]:sm-max:hidden nth-of-type(5)]:sm-max:hidden 
        bg-cover bg-center bg-no-repeat h-[80vh]
        rounded-[50px] text-[#fff] cursor-pointer flex-[0.5] relative transition-[flex] duration-[700ms] ease-in"
      >
        <h3 className="text-2xl absolute bottom-5 left-5 m-0 opacity-0">
          {props.title}
        </h3>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to maintain the active element in the parent component (`Project`) instead of the `Panel` components.

#### Project Component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Panel from "./panel.js";

export default function App() {
  const [activeElement, setActiveElement] = useState(-1);
  return (
    <div
      className="container flex gap-5 w-[100vw] sm:w-[90vw]
        [&>#active]:flex-[5]
        [&>#active>h3]:opacity-100
        [&>#active>h3]:transition-opacity
        [&>#active>h3]:duration-300
        [&>#active>h3]:ease-in
        [&>#active>h3]:delay-[400ms]
      "
    >
      <Panel
        title={"Nature 1"}
        active={activeElement === 1}
        setActive={() => setActiveElement(1)}
      />
      <Panel
        title={"Nature 2"}
        active={activeElement === 2}
        setActive={() => setActiveElement(2)}
      />
      <Panel
        title={"Nature 3"}
        active={activeElement === 3}
        setActive={() => setActiveElement(3)}
      />
      <Panel
        title={"Nature 4"}
        active={activeElement === 4}
        setActive={() => setActiveElement(4)}
      />
      <Panel
        title={"Nature 5"}
        active={activeElement === 5}
        setActive={() => setActiveElement(5)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### Panel Component

```
export default function Panel({ title, setActive, active }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div
        onClick={setActive}
        id={active ? "active" : null}
        className="bg-[url('./assets/img/nature-1.jpg')] nth-of-type(4)]:sm-max:hidden nth-of-type(5)]:sm-max:hidden 
        bg-cover bg-center bg-no-repeat h-[80vh]
        rounded-[50px] text-[#fff] cursor-pointer flex-[0.5] relative transition-[flex] duration-[700ms] ease-in"
      >
        <h3 className="text-2xl absolute bottom-5 left-5 m-0 opacity-0">
          {title}
        </h3>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: const divClassList = `${
    active ? "flex-[5]" : ""
  } ${url} [&:nth-of-type(4)]:sm-max:hidden [&:nth-of-type(5)]:sm-max:hidden 
  bg-cover bg-center bg-no-repeat h-[80vh] rounded-[50px] text-[#fff] 
  cursor-pointer flex-[0.5] relative transition-[flex] duration-[700ms] ease-in`;

With this I add the flex-[5] class when the element is active, but the problem is that,
when the element is NOT active then I get an EMPTY space in my classList.

There is a screen: https://snipboard.io/TLbC7f.jpg

Comment: Instead of setting the classes from the parent, you can do it in the Panel component based on the active prop. Like - `"...your default classes here".concat(active ? 'your active classes' : '')`. Though I am not sure how that space has any effect?

Comment: If it does not have any effect then I am okay with it. Just wanted to know.